# az devops login hangs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm working on Windows 10, Azure PowerShell Az module, DevOps extension 0.18.0

I am logged into a DevOps instance and able to run all related commands.  Now, I need to login to a different org / project.  Every time I execute the login subcommand the window hangs and locks up, I have to restart the PowerShell ISE to try again.

The commands I'm working with (I've tried several variations) are:

```
> az login 
> $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT ='{PAT}' 
> az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/{org} --debug
```

HANGS here!!

Debug logs below

> az devops login --organization [https://dev.azure.com/{org}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D) --debug
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Command argumen...nn', '--debug']:String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   Event: Cli.PreExecute [] Event: CommandParser.OnGlobalArgumentsCreate
> [<function CLILogging.on_global_arguments at 0x03A171E0>, <function 
> OutputProducer.on_global_arguments at 0x03B3AA98>, <function
> CLIQuery.on_global_arguments at 0x03B5CCD8>] Event:
> CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableCreate [] Modules found from index for
> 'devops': ['azext_devops'] Loading command modules: Name              
> Load Time    Groups  Commands Total (0)                 0.000        
> 0         0 These extensions are not installed and will be skipped:
> ['azext_ai_examples', 'azext_ai_did_you_mean_this'] Loading
> extensions: Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands 
> Directory azure-devops              0.110        60       191 
> C:\Users\{username}\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops Total (1)          
> 0.110        60       191   Loaded 60 groups, 191 commands. Found a match in the command table for 'devops login' Event:
> CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableTruncate [<function
> AzCliLogging.init_command_file_logging at 0x03C2B978>]
> az_command_data_logger : command args: devops login --organization {}
> --debug metadata file logging enabled - writing logs to 'C:\Users\{username}\.azure\commands'. Event:
> CommandInvoker.OnPreArgumentLoad [<function
> register_global_subscription_argument.<locals>.add_subscription_parameter
> at 0x03D69660>] Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostArgumentLoad [] Event:
> CommandInvoker.OnPostCommandTableCreate [<function
> register_ids_argument.<locals>.add_ids_arguments at 0x03D69618>,
> <function  register_cache_arguments.<locals>.add_cache_arguments at
> 0x03D69E40>] Event: CommandInvoker.OnCommandTableLoaded [] Event:
> CommandInvoker.OnPreParseArgs [] Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostParseArgs
> [<function OutputProducer.handle_output_argument at 0x03B3AAE0>,
> <function CLIQuery.handle_query_parameter  at 0x03B5CD20>, <function
> register_ids_argument.<locals>.parse_ids_arguments at 0x03D69DF8>,
> <function DevCommandsLoader.post_parse_args at  0x03CF6150>]
> az_command_data_logger : extension name: azure-devops
> az_command_data_logger : extension version: 0.18.0
> ```

- I've restarted windows 10
- I've logged out of az (az logout)
- I've logged out of devops (az devops logout)
- I always run the PowerShell ISE in an elevated permission
  (administrator)

I've confirmed after all of this, I can still access DevOps (pipelines, releases, etc.) from the org/project I started from. so logout is failing as well.

What is going on? Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: May I know that how's the issue going now? Can you get unblock now? Feel free to leave comments below if you still has any question or puzzle.

Comment: logging out does not change the az devops login "hang". I am able to access everything via the portal but not via AZ as described above.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT='{PAT}'` there is no need to run `az devops login`. You can just start using the commands that you want. E.g.: `az repos list --org https://dev.azure.com/{ORG} --project {PROJECT}`.

And it seems that it hangs because it fails to install the keyring~=17.1.1 package (and its deps). You could add that package manually like this: `py -m pip install --target ~\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops keyring~=17.1.1`.

Issue on GitHub: [[Bug] `az devops login` fails the first time unless run as admin · Issue #438 · Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/438)

File where the keyring package version is specified: azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/pip_helper.py

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I need to login to a different org / project.

**Scenario 1:** The target org/project is still under same user account

If the target org/project you want to work with is still **under same user account**, at this moment, you don't need log out and re-login.

Just run below command to change the default org/project using:

```
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/{org name}
```

Then you will be available to work with another org/project without re-login.

**Scenario 2:** The target org/project is under another user account

If the actual scenario is you have to change to login with another account to work with that org/project, please run below command to log out firstly:

```
az logout --username "{another account}"
```

Then re-run `az login` to login with another account address. You should be successful now .

[image]

Comment: logging out does not change the az devops login "hang".  I am able to access everything via the portal but not via AZ as described above.

Comment: @user2503078 what I mentioned above is not using az devops login command. If you are able to access everything via one account. At this moment, you just need to reset the default config to access another org.

Comment: @user2503078 As you mentioned, logging out does not change the az devops login “hang”. Do you mean you are always encounter stuck issue even if you have log out? On my side, if I log out firstly, I will be able to login again. (I ever encountered same issue as you)

Comment: I am able to use az logout and then after az login, access devops.  But if I run "az devops login" it hangs every time, no matter what I do.

Comment: @user2503078 One further question, log out with `az logout —username “user accout”` command? And when you trying to access another org, are you still need using same account? Or need change to another account?

Comment: Hi, after logging out, I would have to login again using a different username to access the DevOps resources.  This seems to work, meaning az login, but az devops login never works.  I've simply stopped trying to use it as the login from az seems to set the appropriate access. HTH

Comment: @user2503078. AWW, great! That's what I want to express in my answer. If you need to change to use another account before you access another org, at this moment, you need log out firstly. AND, you don't need log in again if accessing another org don't need switch to new account. Just pls change the default configuration of command and you should be able to continue to work with new org. See the scenario 1 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I am on another windows user account that doesn't have administrator access.  I would run powershell as administrator and give my other windows credentials to authenticate.
But running powershell this way didn't bring up the browser to sign-in.  If I run it not as administrator then it runs fine and the prompt works.